# Django - Passing ID into url template tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

How do I insert an id inside a url template tag using javascript? I tried this way and I did not get it. Can not find the route in the urls.py.

```
function Edit(pk){
    window.location.assign("{% url 'authentication:edit_user' "+${pk}+" %}");
}
<!-- Other way -->
function Edit(pk){
    window.location.assign("{% url 'authentication:edit_user' "+pk+" %}");
}
```

Error is:

> Reverse for 'edit_user' with arguments '('+${pk}+',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried:
>   ['authentication\/user\/edit\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

Answer (score 1):

This can't possibly work. Template tags are evaluated server-side, well before the client-side Javascript can run.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatinate the string. The url tag takes parameter. So you can change your code to

```
window.location.assign("{% url 'authentication:edit_user' pk %}");
```

Reference - [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I do not concatenate this error appears and not find the route.
Reverse for 'edit_user' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['authentication\\/user\\/edit\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Comment: @DevPython, That error indicates the `pk` field is empty. You may not be passing it to template properly.